# Sesam http transform namespaces

Tags: sesam

I have an http transform in Sesam that reads entities from a REST api and writes to a dataset.

```
{
  "_id": "read-entities",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "dataset",
    "dataset": "global-entities"
  },
  "transform": [{
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["copy", "*"],
        ["add", "::foo",
          ["first", "_S.entity:foo"]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "http",
    "system": "entities",
    "url": "/transform"
  }, {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["add", "entities", "_S.response"]
      ]
    }
  }]
}
```

This is what I get in response:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "namespace:fuubar",
    "entities:entity": [
      {
        "foo":"baz"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The entities arrives without namespace, except for the "_id" from the source dataset, is there a method for adding the namespace for the "read-entites"-pipe?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by applying a rule to every object where you map the keys of the object by prefixing them with your namespace and conditionally apply this rule recursively if the value is a dictionary (JSON object):

```
{
  "_id": "recursively-add-namespaces",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "embedded",
    "entities": [{
      "_id": "namespace:fuubar",
      "entities:entity": [{
        "foo": "baz",
        "nested": {
          "bar": "foobar"
        }
      }]
    }]
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["add", "::namespaced-entity",
          ["apply", "add-my-ns", "_S.entities:entity"]
        ]
      ],
      "add-my-ns": [
        ["merge",
          ["map-dict",
            ["concat", "my-ns:", "_."],
            ["if",
              ["is-dict", "_."],
              ["apply", "add-my-ns", "_."], "_."], "_S."]
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  "add_namespaces": false
}
```

This gives the following result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "namespace:fuubar",
    "namespaced-entity": [
      {
        "my-ns:foo": "baz",
        "my-ns:nested": {
          "my-ns:bar": "foobar"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```